# Page number export in Aux file

Tags: auxiliary-files, totalcount

Need to export in separate file to getting First & Last page number and Total pagecount using aux file,
Please find MWE file as below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[totpages,user]{zref}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\AtEndDocument{LastPage}
\AtBeginDocument{FirstPage}

\newcommand{\totpages}{\ifnum\ztotpages=1 1 page \else  \ztotpages\ pages \fi}

\makeatletter
\newwrite\file
\immediate\openout\file=filename_pgcount.xml\relax
\immediate\write\file{
<ArticleMetaData><PageCount Type="PageExtent"><fpage>\pageref{FirstPage}</fpage><lpage>\pageref{LastPage}</lpage><tpage>\totpages</tpage></PageCount>
</ArticleMetaData>
}
\closeout\file
\makeatother

\setcounter{page}{101}
\begin{document}
\totpages
\vskip50pt

\lipsum[1-12]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an XY problem, if I understand correctly.

Instead of parsing type-setting instructions in `.aux` files and macros (which is possible), it is easier to store and write the values directly.

At begin document, store the printable, arabic, form (here, the characters `101`) of the `page` counter.

In the actual document output, the `page` counter may be typeset as `ci` (Roman), `101` (arabic), `१०१` (Devanagari),  etc.

Likewise, at end document, store the printable, arabic, form (the characters `103`) of the `page` counter at that moment.

Note that (lastpage)-(firstpage)+1 may not give the real number of pages, since the `page` counter can be reset at any time inside the document.

The `zref` package, in module `totpages`, defines an independent page-counting counter, and provides a macro, `\ztotpages`, for storing the printable form of the number of absolute pages (here, `3`).

Also at end document, output the `.xml` file.

Requires 2 or more compilation runs for `ztotpages` to pick up a settled value from the `.aux` file, since inserting table of contents etc will add additional pages.

The `.xml` file then has:

[image: xml_contents]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{zref-totpages}

\newcounter{xmyFP}
\newcounter{xmyLP}
\newcommand\valxmyFP{\setcounter{xmyFP}{\thepage}}
\newcommand\valxmyLP{\setcounter{xmyLP}{\thepage}}

\newcommand\outputmetainfo{%
\newwrite\file
\immediate\openout\file=filename_pgcount.xml\relax
\immediate\write\file{
<ArticleMetaData>
<PageCount Type="PageExtent">
<fpage>\arabic{xmyFP}</fpage>
<lpage>\arabic{xmyLP}</lpage>
<tpage>\ztotpages</tpage>
</PageCount>
</ArticleMetaData>
}
\closeout\file
}

\setcounter{page}{101}
\AtBeginDocument{\valxmyFP}
\AtEndDocument{\valxmyLP\outputmetainfo}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-12]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you Cicada, your answer is most helpful to us, one small query, in my document I have inserted two full page figure starting of \begin{document}, need to exclude those two pages in the total page count (\ztotpages-2), is this possible to less counter?

Comment: @RajeshN I don't know. Probably yes, I would expect. Ask a separate question, so more people will see. That will improve the chances of an answer.